# Change the Points Earned in Idea activity in salesforce

Tags: community, ideas, reputation

In the [Ideas Documentation](https://na31.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_ideas_implementation_guide.pdf) page 13, i have seen the points allocated to ideas activity. i want to change thses points allocated to idea activities. is there any way to change these points.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, votes on Ideas connot be changed afterwards. In fact, allowing this is an idea brought up in the succes community, see: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq7OAAS